# What exactly does .apply do?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Never seen the .apply method before. Can someone explains to me what it does? This is taken from http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/

```
var app = app || {}; 
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.Todo,
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage(’todos-backbone’),
completed: function() {
    return this.filter(function( todo ) {
        return todo.get(’completed’); 
    });
},
remaining: function() {
    return this.without.apply( this, this.completed() );
}, 
nextOrder: function() {
    if ( !this.length ) { 
        return 1;
    }
    return this.last().get(’order’) + 1; },
comparator: function( todo ) { 
    return todo.get(’order’);
} 
});
app.Todos = new TodoList();
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: It lets you change the context of `this` and pass an array as arguments.

Answer (score 8):

The function object comes with `apply()` and `call()` methods. They both effectively do the same thing, except slightly differently. What they do is allow you to define the `this` pointer inside of that function's scope. So for example, if you do:

```
function myFunc(param1, param2) { alert(this) }

var first = 'foo';
var second = 'bar';

myFunc.call('test', first, second); //alerts 'test'

myFunc.apply('test', [first, second]); //alerts 'test'
```

In both methods, you pass the `this` pointer as the first parameter. In the `call()` method, you pass all subsequent parameters in sequential order after that, such that the second argument becomes the first parameter of myFunc. In the `apply()` method, you pass the extra parameters in as an array.

Comment: i have a question though, since we are passing "this" as the first argument how does that work?

Comment: @user1074316 The magic of the language.  It could (kind of) be written by assigning the function to a property of the object, then calling it with the arguments.  Of course it is implemented by the language and there is no temporary value.