# f.apply(null, arguments) and f(arguments)

Tags: javascript, eloquent

This is code in eloquentjavascript:

```
function transparentWrapping(f) {
  return function() {
    return f.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

This is my code. I'm not using `apply` method:

```
function myTransparentWrapping(f) {
  return function() {//don't use apply
    return f(arguments);
  };
}
```

What is the difference between the two?

Change the angle, whether it can be said that the difference between f (arguments) and null.f (arguments)。

Comment: Does it work and you're trying to know the difference? Just to be clear what your question is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does .apply do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317526/what-exactly-does-apply-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply() method calls a function with a given this value, and arguments provided as an array.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

So, your first function will return a function that can be executed later on with the arguments provided to it.
For Example:

```
function add(x, y){ return x + y }
var functionX = transparentWrapping(add);
functionX(1, 2) // this will output 3
```

And your second function will immediately invoke the passed function with parameters provided to it as an array-like object(arguments). In the previous example, your f will be called like `f([1, 2])` which means your x is [1,2] and your y is undefined. (x + y = [object Arguments]undefined)

```
function add(x, y){ return x + y }
var functionY = myTransparentWrapping(add);
functionY(1, 2) // will return [object Arguments]undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

In your own implementation

```
function myTransparentWrapping(f) {
  return function() {//don't use apply
    return f(arguments);
  };
}
```

you pass `arguments` as parameter to `f` function. But `arguments` is an array-like object ([MDN: Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)). What you actually need is to use spread operator instead ([MDN: Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)). So your own implementation should be looking something like this:

```
function myTransparentWrapping(f) {
  return function() {//don't use apply
    return f(...arguments);
  };
}
```